# Convert a vector into logical matrix

Tags: r

Is there a native R function that will take an input vector and return the corresponding binary matrix where the matrix has the same number of columns as unique values in the input vector?

For example, given `x <- 1:3`, I want to return the following matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

The functions `contrasts` gets close, but I can't seem to get around the n-1 columns returned:

```
> contrasts(as.factor(x))
  2 3
1 0 0
2 1 0
3 0 1
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether the factor will only ever contain a single observation from each level? Or can there be multiple observations per level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`model.matrix()` might help here, but you need to suppress the intercept:

```
> model.matrix(~ factor(1:3) - 1)
  factor(1:3)1 factor(1:3)2 factor(1:3)3
1            1            0            0
2            0            1            0
3            0            0            1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$`factor(1:3)`
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Something slightly more complex:

```
> set.seed(1)
> fac <- factor(sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
> model.matrix(~ fac - 1)
   fac1 fac2 fac3
1     1    0    0
2     0    1    0
3     0    1    0
4     0    0    1
5     1    0    0
6     0    0    1
7     0    0    1
8     0    1    0
9     0    1    0
10    1    0    0
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$fac
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, `contrasts` is what you want.

```
contrasts(as.factor(1:3), contrasts=FALSE)

  1 2 3
1 1 0 0
2 0 1 0
3 0 0 1
```

Comment: BAH - I totally failed at reading the documentation...thank you sir.

Comment: @Chase If **that** *is* what you want, what is wrong with `diag(3)`??? Note that for the more complex `fac` in my answer, `contrasts(fac, contrasts = FALSE)` doesn't give the same result as `model.matrix()`. Perhaps I misunderstood what you wanted, but if I did, `diag()` is sufficient no?

Comment: @GavinSimpson - good intuition, I'm all over the place this morning. Your second example is more representative of my real use case. Must consume coffee and/or sleep. Thanks again.