# R : How to turn categorical variable into dummies, and collapsing ID variables

Tags: r

I am working on R.

I have a dataframe with 2 columns : an identifier, with some identifiers present multiple times, and a categorical variable.

Each identifier can have multiple categories.

I'm trying to turn this into a dataset with only dummy variables instead of the categorical variable. This also requires to have only one line for each identifier variable, even though some are present multiple times in the original dataframe (in order to match multiple categories).

In other words, I'm trying to turn this :

```
data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B"), 
       Color = c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Red"))
```

into this :

```
data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), 
       Color_Red = c(1, 1, 0), 
       Color_Blue = c(1, 1, 1), 
       Color_Green = c(0, 0, 1))
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What about using `table` ?

Comment: Thank you that obviously works great I don't know why i didn't think of it !

Comment: For others finding this page looking for the traditional meaning of dummy variables, see `model.matrix` and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12843557/8262231

Comment: @W.Murphy also useful to look at package `dummies` and function `dummy` or `dummy.data.frame`. Here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dummies/dummies.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution with a bit of reshaping:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B"), 
                Color = c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Blue", "Red"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(counts = 1) %>%
  spread(Color, counts, fill = 0)

#   ID Blue Green Red
# 1  A    1     0   1
# 2  B    1     0   1
# 3  C    1     1   0
```

Comment: That works great thank you ! Of course I could have thought of `table` that works as well :)

Comment: It works, but won't give you a data.frame output, but an object of class "table" ( i.e. an array of integer values).

Answer (score 2):

```
with(df,table(ID,Color))
   Color
ID  Blue Green Red
  A    1     0   1
  B    1     0   1
  C    1     1   0
```

If you needed the result to be a data frame you can reshape

```
dcast(data.frame(with(df,table(ID,Color))),ID~Color)
  ID Blue Green Red
1  A    1     0   1
2  B    1     0   1
3  C    1     1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df <- dcast(df, ID ~ Color)
df[,2:4 := lapply(.SD,function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,1)}), .SDcols = 2:4]
```

Result:

```
    ID Blue Green Red
1:  A    1     0   1
2:  B    1     0   1
3:  C    1     1   0
```